# Recursive query with child in different column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a recursive table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CATEGORIE](
            [id_categorie] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
            [Nom] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
            [_Description] [varchar](2048) NULL,
            [id_categorie_1] [int] NULL,
            [id_codesActivite] [int] NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [id_categorie] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CATEGORIE]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT 
[FK_CATEGORIE_id_categorie_1] FOREIGN KEY([id_categorie_1])
REFERENCES [dbo].[CATEGORIE] ([id_categorie])
GO
```

And i would like a query that result a table with all child in different column , like this :

```
COL1 | COL2    | COL3
----------------------------
CAT1 |         |
CAT1 | SCAT1-1 |
CAT1 | SCAT1-1 | SSCAT1-1-1
CAT1 | SCAT1-1 | SSCAT1-1-2
CAT1 | SCAT1-1 | SSCAT1-1-3
CAT1 | SCAT1-2 |
CAT1 | SCAT1-2 | SSCAT1-2-1
CAT1 | SCAT1-2 | SSCAT1-2-2
CAT1 | SCAT1-2 | SSCAT1-2-3
CAT2 |         |
CAT2 | SCAT2-1 | 
CAT2 | SCAT2-2 | 
CAT3 |         |
CAT3 | SCAT3-1 | 
CAT3 | SCAT3-1 | SSCAT3-1-1
CAT3 | SCAT3-1 | SSCAT3-1-2
```

I think i must use recursive query, like in this link
https://sqlpro.developpez.com/cours/sqlserver/cte-recursives/

But i can't find the good one.

Thanks

EDIT :

For the moment i have a view with this code :

```
SELECT
  (SELECT Nom
   FROM dbo.CATEGORIE AS CAT3
   WHERE (id_categorie =
        (SELECT id_categorie_1
         FROM dbo.CATEGORIE AS CAT2
         WHERE (id_categorie = dbo.CATEGORIE.id_categorie_1)))) AS CAT1,

  (SELECT Nom
   FROM dbo.CATEGORIE AS CAT2
   WHERE (id_categorie = dbo.CATEGORIE.id_categorie_1)) AS CAT2,
   Nom AS CAT3,
   id_categorie
FROM dbo.CATEGORIE
```

It's work, but i need to "shift" the column in my C# code

```
+------+--------+----------+--------------+
| CAT1 | CAT2   | CAT3     | id_categorie |
+------+--------+----------+--------------+
| NULL | NULL   | CAT1     | 392          |
+------+--------+----------+--------------+
| NULL | CAT1   | CAT1-1   | 393          |
+------+--------+----------+--------------+
| NULL | CAT1   | CAT1-2   | 394          |
+------+--------+----------+--------------+
| NULL | CAT1   | CAT1-3   | 395          |
+------+--------+----------+--------------+
| CAT1 | CAT1-1 | CAT1-1-1 | 396          |
+------+--------+----------+--------------+
| CAT1 | CAT1-1 | CAT1-1-2 | 397          |
+------+--------+----------+--------------+
| CAT1 | CAT1-2 | CAT1-2-1 | 398          |
+------+--------+----------+--------------+
| NULL | NULL   | CAT2     | 399          |
+------+--------+----------+--------------+
| NULL | NULL   | CAT3     | 400          |
+------+--------+----------+--------------+
| NULL | CAT3   | CAT3-1   | 401          |
+------+--------+----------+--------------+
| NULL | CAT3   | CAT3-2   | 402          |
+------+--------+----------+--------------+
| CAT3 | CAT3-2 | CAT3-2-1 | 403          |
+------+--------+----------+--------------+
| CAT3 | CAT3-2 | CAT3-2-2 | 404          |
+------+--------+----------+--------------+
| CAT3 | CAT3-2 | CAT3-2-3 | 405          |
+------+--------+----------+--------------+
```

Comment: How many possible hierarchy levels are there?  Can this number of levels increase?  Why do you want to format your result in this way?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: For the moment there si only 3 level. The datas come from nest combox, an the query is to display all the categorie tree for edit purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `recursive CTE`. Using a `seq` which is concatenated with every child member. This supports recursion upto max 9 levels. If you require more, use digits like `01` instead of `1`. Also add columns accordingly in the select statement.

```
Create table #temp ([id_categorie] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, Name varchar(50),
            [id_categorie_1] [int] NULL)

Insert into #temp values 
('A',null),
('B',1),
('C',2),
('D',2),
('E',1),
('F',3),
('G',2),
('H',3)


With
rcte as
(
    -- Anchor member
    select  *, seq = convert(varchar(100), '1'), 
               NAMES = Cast('<root> <myvalue>' + Name as varchar(max))
    from    #temp
    where   [id_categorie_1] is null

    union all

    -- Recursive member
    select  c.*, seq = convert(varchar(100), 
                    r.seq 
                +   convert(varchar(10), 
                    row_number() over (partition by r.seq order by c.id_categorie_1))),
                 NAMES = CAST((r.Names + '</myvalue> <myvalue>' + c.Name) as varchar(max))
    from    #temp c
    inner join rcte r   on  c.id_categorie_1  = r.[id_categorie]
)
, cte as 
(select *, Convert(xml, Names + '</myvalue>   </root> ') as x
 from rcte) 
SELECT distinct
  T.c.value('(/root/myvalue)[1]','VARCHAR(20)'),
  T.c.value('(/root/myvalue)[2]','VARCHAR(20)'),
  T.c.value('(/root/myvalue)[3]','VARCHAR(20)'),
  T.c.value('(/root/myvalue)[4]','VARCHAR(20)'),
  seq
FROM cte cross apply x.nodes('/root/myvalue') T(c)
ORDER BY seq
```

Comment: How can i add the id of the last categorie : for CAT1 > CAT1-2 > CAT1-2-3, i need the id of CAT1-2-3

Comment: Just add it in the `Select` statement

Comment: In which select ? i am a bit lost. Thanks

Comment: Add `id_categorie` in the last select

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working ! (I tried with c.id_categorie)

Answer (score 0):

Try to build the parent query first and then the child query however deep you want.

for example if the parent is retrieved with id_categorie_1='Parent' then the parent query

```
Select id_categorie AS COL1 FROM CATEGORIE WHERE id_categorie_1='Parent'
```

for the child of parent(1st generation)

```
Select catPARENT.id_categorie AS COL1, ISNULL(catChild1.id_categorie,'') AS COL2 
FROM CATEGORIE AS catPARENT LEFT JOIN CATEGORIE AS catChild1
ON catPARENT.id_categorie=catChild1.id_categorie_1
WHERE catPARENT.id_categorie_1='Parent'
```

And the answer to your question, the grandchild (2nd generation)

```
Select catPARENT.id_categorie AS COL1, ISNULL(catChild1.id_categorie,'') AS COL2
, ISNULL(catChild2.id_categorie,'') AS COL3
FROM CATEGORIE AS catPARENT LEFT JOIN CATEGORIE AS catChild1
ON catPARENT.id_categorie=catChild1.id_categorie_1 LEFT JOIN CATEGORIE AS catChild2
ON catChild1.id_categorie=catChild2.id_categorie_1 
WHERE catPARENT.id_categorie_1='Parent'
```

Comment: Your code seems to mix categorie from different level in the first column

Answer (score 0):

If you want exactly three columns, you can do:

```
select c.name, c1.nom, c2.nom
from categorie c left join
     categorie c1
     on c1.id_categorie_1 = c.id_categorie left join
     categorie c2
     on c2.id_categorie_1 = c1.id_categorie
where c.id_categorie_1 is null;
```

This gets the top level categories and the next two levels.  There is no need for a recursive query for this example.

Comment: I have three columns but the id_categorie_2 dose not exist

Comment: @RémiG . . . That was a typo.

Comment: When i run your query, there is line missing, see my edit above